# How can I files backup in current date form local server in linux/unix?

Tags: java, linux, perl, shell, unix

I am new to Unix/Linux system. Now I trying current date files copy from local server in linux/unix platform. But I can't do best because I don't how to start this and how solve this problems. But I found out some sites but i couldn't understand about this? Can you any one help for this process...

My concept is "Current date file copy from local server to my PC platform unix/linux" How can I start this?

please can you anyone help this.... thanks advance... I need any option program for this by delevelped"

Answer (score 1):

Just connect to your remote server as

```
$ sudo ssh [user_name]@[host_name] -p[port_no]
$ password:
```

Then you can actually check out the files that are created, modified accessed using -mtime command in linux, for example

```
$ sudo find /source_directory -mtime n
```

The -mtime is modified time.

Replace n with suitable value, it works like n*24hrs ago.

you can also make use of command like ctime, atime for changed, accessed file in the same way as mtime.

May be, you can make use piping of command like

```
$ sudo find /source_directory -mtime 1 | scp [user_name]@[hostname]:/path/to/remote/file [user_name]@[hostname]:/path/to/local/file
```

or simply find the file and then copy it with scp command.

for more details, you can go through [delete-move-copy-files-of-specific-date](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/delete-move-copy-files-of-specific-date-245888/) &
[scp help](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy a file from one host to another, right?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy

You really Need to work on your question asking skills though, it is really hard to understand what you mean.